# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

It seems that he added `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` to the communication code, but for some reason it gives an error when starting the `Spring-application`.

Class Customer:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Customer extends User {

    public Customer(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Customer(String name, String lastName,
                    double wallet, List<Order> orderList){ // Пользовательский конструктор создается,
                                                            // когда нам нужно создать новый экземпляр,
                                                            // но у нас еще нет ID.
        super(name, lastName);
        this.wallet = wallet;
        this.orderList = orderList;
    }


    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private double wallet;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Order> orderList;


    // Методы
    public void depositMoney(){// Внести деньги на счет

        }

    public void withdrawMoney(){// Вывести деньги со счета

        }

    public void makeOrder(){// Сделать заказ

        }
}
```

Class Order:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Order {

    public Order(){

    }

    public Order(short orderNumber, Customer customer, String address,
                 String phoneNumber, Date dateOrder, Cook cook, List<Dish> dishes) {

        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber= phoneNumber;
        this.dateOrder = dateOrder;
        this.cook = cook;
        this.dishes = dishes;
    }

    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private short orderNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Customer customer;

    private String address;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private Date dateOrder;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Cook cook;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    private enum orderStatus{}


    // Методы
    public double calculateCost(){// Посчитать стоимость заказа
        return 0;
    }

    public void setReview(){// Оставить отзыв и оценку

    }

    public void cancelOrder(){// Отменить заказ

    }
}
```

```java
2020-03-25 10:21:34.649 ERROR 17876 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.tinychiefdelights.model.Dish.order references an unknown entity: com.tinychiefdelights.model.Order
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.tinychiefdelights.TinyChiefDelightsApplication.main(TinyChiefDelightsApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.tinychiefdelights.model.Dish.order references an unknown entity: com.tinychiefdelights.model.Order
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1823) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class Order import @entity from `javax.persistence` instead of `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`